# Memory leak in my copy constructor for a linked list C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a copy constructor for my class "IntList", but I keep getting a memory leak error and am having difficulty identifying it!

Here is my implementation of the copy constructor!

```
IntList::IntList(const IntList& source) {
  Node *y = source.first;
  first = new Node;
  Node *x = first;
  while(y->next != nullptr){
    x->info = y->info;
    x -> next = new Node;
    x = x->next;
    y = y->next;
  }

  x->next = nullptr;
  x->info = y->info;

}
```

Here is the Inklist Class!

```
class IntList {

public:

    // ctor and 3 methods already done in intlist.cpp:                          
    IntList();              // constructor                                      
    void append(int value); // append value at end of list                      
    void print() const;     // print values separate by ' '                     
    int count() const;      // return count of values                           

    // dtor, copy ctor and 6 other METHODS YOU MUST                             
    // IMPLEMENT IN intlist.cpp:                                                
    ~IntList();                      // destructor                              
    IntList(const IntList& source); //copy constructor (deep copy)              
    int sum() const;                 // sum of all values                       
    bool contains(int value) const;  // true if value in list                   
    int max() const;                 // maximum value                           
    double average() const;          // average of all values                   
    void insertFirst(int value);     // insert new first value                  

    IntList& operator=(const IntList& source); //overloaded                     

private:

    // definition of Node structure (DO NOT CHANGE):                            
    struct Node {
        int info;
        Node *next;
    };

    Node *first; // pointer to first node                                       

};
```

Comment: Memory leaks happen when you use `new` without a corresponding `delete`. Also, why make your own linked list when the STL has a perfectly good one?

Comment: If you `new` it and you (still) own it (which in this case your class does), you need to `delete` it.

Answer (score 2):

Your destructor needs to traverse the list and `delete` all the nodes you `new`'ed